# Streamed binary to PDF - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, binary

After requested a Web-service, i get the following answer (PDF file Streamed)

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-GB) /StructTreeRoot 10 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
................. continue .......................
```

So far, i can generate the pdf file using windows.open(application/pdf;base64, url).

What i really need is to save the pdf document in the storage!

How can i generate the PDF file with the response above?

Tks

Comment: You probably want to change the headers of the response, so the browser will show you the "save" dialog.

Comment: What i need is to save the file directly in the storage, without open a dialog in the browser!

Comment: That's not possible. You can't _force_ the browser to save items without having the user confirm it.

Comment: what does this sentence mean?  "But i need to be able to save the document(in the computer storage), instead open it in a new tab."  I don't understand. Are you trying to save the file or display it in a new tab?  Your words are not clear.

Comment: I need to save the file, not open in the browser!

Comment: Really hard to do it right cross-platform, here is what is done in Mozilla's PDF.js https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/download_manager.js#L20

Answer (score -2):

I do something similiar with my site at http://dogfeatherdesign.com/ttn_js, except I'm going from Canvas to pdf files, when the user hits a print button.  Depending on which OS and browser, the download happens automatically. (Note: Safari is NOT good for this.)  I'm using the libraries [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Here's my code:

```
$('#dte_onPrintClick').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        html2canvas($("#canvas_dte"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', paperInfo.paperSize);
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('output-file.pdf');
            }
        });
    });
```

now obviously you are going from pdf to pdf, but I'm guessing the `doc = new jsPDF(), doc.addXXX, doc.save(filename.pdf)` might have some merit for you.

Update:
Without specifics on the pdf feed, I'm not quite sure how to be more helpful, except to say that what you want to do should be achievable on most modern browsers. You CAN save the pdf content as a file withOUT user input, via the .save() call listed above (in many, but not all browsers).

If its a hack you are looking for, you could catch the pdf stream, save it as an image in a hidden div, then convert it back to pdf and do the doc.save() function.  You'd have to add lengthy time delays to ensure the feed finishes, and the image populates, etc, but it should be do-able.

I do see a putstream() function, getBlob() function, and getArrayBuffer() function to jsPDF library, so its quite possible one of those would work directly to help catch the pdf and generate a stored document, all on the fly via JavaScript.

Edit #2:  Heres the immediate download, [no user interaction jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/z4gd1ghg/1/).  I'm actually surprised this works that way, but so be it.   I agree, normally a file save requires user intervention, but this download thing just works. Frankly I'm surprised at this too.

Comment: This code really is useless without the implementation of that `.save` function. Basically, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Both of those are open source libraries available on github.  The implementation code is all there.  I'm confused.  You don't like the .save function (but that is EXACTLY what the Bruno was asking for.. )

Comment: You're not even linking to the libraries. Even then, linked libraries can be deleted over time, invalidating the answer. ___All___ code required to answer a question should be in the answer itself. Also: _"You CAN save the pdf content as a file withOUT user input"_ - Nope, that is not possible. A save can only ever be initiated by the user. Be it from a clicked link, or a save dialog.

Comment: Er no.  From the "how to answer a question..." hints and guidelines on this site:  `Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. ANY ANSWER THAT GETS THE ASKER GOING IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION IS HELPFUL, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.` (Emphasis added.)  Is 'save' === 'download'??

Comment: _"What i need is to save the file directly in the storage, without open a dialog in the browser!"  – Bruno 2 hours ago_. That fiddle opens a "Save file" dialog, which requires user interaction. This is _not_ what the OP wants. Furthermore, you're basically telling the user to use library X, which would make this question a library request -> off-topic.

Comment: Er, wait.  I did not get a save file dialog.  honest.  What browser / OS are you using.  Apologies, not trying to be too flippant here.  I just want to learn more.

Comment: Library request?  Huh? Half the responses on all of stackoverflow refer to a library (or other software package) as a means to solving software issues.  Could you provide a reference that gives that guidance?  Would you try the fiddle in chrome?  thx.

Comment: Chrome, IE and Firefox show a "Save" dialog, Safari doesn't do _anything_ (Not even an error), and Opera just saves the item. (All of them on the latest version at time of posting)

Comment: I generally work in Chrome on both Win7 and Linux, and I know there is not dialog there on either OS.. (I've been using that print button a lot lately).  Possible I've got a persistent setting from a long time ago?  Could that be a security setup thing?  I'm surprised we have such different observations on this one.  I do see in Chrome settings where there is a default download location listed, and a check box that says [ ] ask where to save each file before downloading.  Mine is NOT checked.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a user setting. This setting can't be ignored.

Comment: Why you are calling jsPDF as "PDF.js"?

Comment: @Cerbrus   Something is definitely odd here.  I've just tested that JS fiddle on other computers, and I'm seeing instant downloads when ever Chrome is used (on mac, linux and win7)  Other browsers display a save popup. You said you don't see that at all.  When you uncheck your setting "ask where to save each file before downloading" do you still see that Save box, or does the pdf file immediately download without user interaction or approval?  Is this a bug in Chrome?   Oh, and exactly what do you mean by `This setting can't be ignored.`  What setting?

Comment: Most of my installed browsers show a dialog. The "Ask where to save" - setting.